# How transaction function in Codeigniter 3 works with the query?

Tags: php, transactions, codeigniter-3

So i have this query in my Models.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere2);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere3);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere4);
$this->db->update($somequeryhere7);
$this->db->update($somequeryhere21);
$this->db->delete($somequeryhere10);
if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
   $this->db->trans_rollback(); return false;
}else{
   $this->db->trans_commit(); return true;
}
```

The transaction sure works well. But it's confusing when i tried to die the PHP process in the middle of query like below query.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere2);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere3);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere4);
die;
$this->db->update($somequeryhere7);
$this->db->update($somequeryhere21);
$this->db->delete($somequeryhere10);
if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
   $this->db->trans_rollback(); return false;
}else{
   $this->db->trans_commit(); return true;
}
```

The transaction still works. I thought the PHP didn't reach `$this->db->trans_status()` so the transaction will not working, but this also works like  using or without using `$this->db->trans_status()`. Could someone explain this ?

I have tried to used `$this->db->trans_start();` and `$this->db->trans_complete();` and the transaction rollback still executed.

Comment: you are using transaction manual mode.https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html.
try `$this->db->trans_start();` i think then transaction will not commit if you put die

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha ok, i will try.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha i have tried it, and the transaction still execute even i used `$this->db->trans_start();`  and `$this->db->trans_complete();`

Answer (score 1):

If you Put a Die in middle of the code after trans_begin(). 
it will not commit, If you want to check the status of insert update data, you must not use the trans method for this one.

Because for trans method - commit or rollback need must to execute the query

```
//$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere2);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere3);
$this->db->insert($somequeryhere4);
die;
$this->db->update($somequeryhere7);
$this->db->update($somequeryhere21);
$this->db->delete($somequeryhere10);
```